# Passing data from two activities to a third activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent

have total 3 activites. I pass the data from the first activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Movie_rev_fulldis_activity.class);
intent.putExtra("mov_pos", position + "");
startActivity(intent);
```

this working fine all data visible to my second activity but i want to display 
one filed item to third activity when i click second activity image

here my second activity

```
youtube_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent youtube= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),PlayYouTube1st.class);
            youtube.putExtra("youtubeLink",youtubeLink);
            startActivity(youtube);
           // Toast.makeText(Movie_rev_fulldis_activity.this,
                   // youtubeLink, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
});

youtubeLink=Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getYoutubeLink();


Toast.makeText(Movie_rev_fulldis_activity.this,
   Reviews_update.revData.get(mov_pos).getYoutubeLink(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

mov_pos=Integer.parseInt((getIntent().getExtras()).getString("mov_pos"));
```

in second activity i am getting values but when i send one filed to third activity that value passing null any one please help me i stuck in their,

I want to show YoutubeLink field sencnd activity to third activity how to parse that any one please help

Comment: Please add complete source code, to answer correctly

Comment: what is showing in your toast ?

Comment: it showing null values@sourabhbans

Comment: do you check that your youtubelink is not null? and do you check that you use same key in third activity?

Answer (score 0):

In `FastActivity`:

```
Intent in = new Intent(FastActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
in.putExtra("a", yourdata);
startActivity(in);
```

In `SecondActivity`:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

if (extras != null) {
    String a = extras.getString("a");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make that `variable` **static** and then pass

Your `variable object` reference get change in the `THIRD Activity` so, it returns `null`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use any static variable and use it in any class

```
static int a = 5;
```

And in any other class

```
int b = classname.a;
```

classname is the class where static variable is declared.